# How to Disable Ctrl-C /Ctrl-S While Running a Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

By default, batch files can be terminated when the user presses Ctrl-C and can be paused by pressing Ctrl-S.  Is there a way to disable this?  The MS-DOS BREAK command apparently used to do this, but it is now ignored in Windows.  I need something that works in WinNT 4.0  and Win2K.

Answer (score 1):

ignore confirmed by help:

> C:>break /? Sets or Clears Extended
>   CTRL+C checking on DOS system
>
> This is present for Compatibility with
>   DOS systems. It has no effect under
>   Windows.

partial solution:
start /MIN /B myscript.cmd :

```
B           Start application without creating a new window. The
            application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application
            enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt
            the application.
```